# Code optimisation: Converting dataframe to numpy's ndarray

Tags: python, performance, python-3.x, numpy, pandas

I am working with a dataframe of over 21M rows.

```
df.head()
+---+-----------+-------+--------------+-----------+----------------+------------+
|   |    id     | speed | acceleration |   jerk    | bearing_change | travelmode |
+---+-----------+-------+--------------+-----------+----------------+------------+
| 0 | 533815001 | 17.63 | 0.000000     | -0.000714 | 209.028008     |          3 |
| 1 | 533815001 | 17.63 | -0.092872    | 0.007090  | 56.116237      |          3 |
| 2 | 533815001 | 0.17  | 1.240000     | -2.040000 | 108.494680     |          3 |
| 3 | 533815001 | 1.41  | -0.800000    | 0.510000  | 11.847480      |          3 |
| 4 | 533815001 | 0.61  | -0.290000    | 0.150000  | 36.7455703     |          3 |
+---+-----------+-------+--------------+-----------+----------------+------------+

df.info()
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 21713545 entries, 0 to 21713544
Data columns (total 6 columns):
 #   Column          Dtype  
---  ------          -----  
 0   id              int64  
 1   speed           float64
 2   acceleration    float64
 3   jerk            float64
 4   bearing_change  float64
 5   travelmode      int64  
dtypes: float64(4), int64(2)
memory usage: 994.0 MB
```

I would like to convert this dataframe to a multi-dimensional array. So I write this function to do it:

```
def transform(dataframe, chunk_size=5):
    
    grouped = dataframe.groupby('id')

    # initialize accumulators
    X, y = np.zeros([0, 1, chunk_size, 4]), np.zeros([0,])

    # loop over each group (df[df.id==1] and df[df.id==2])
    for _, group in grouped:

        inputs = group.loc[:, 'speed':'bearing_change'].values
        label = group.loc[:, 'travelmode'].values[0]

        # calculate number of splits
        N = (len(inputs)-1) // chunk_size

        if N > 0:
            inputs = np.array_split(
                 inputs, [chunk_size + (chunk_size*i) for i in range(N)])
        else:
            inputs = [inputs]

        # loop over splits
        for inpt in inputs:
            inpt = np.pad(
                inpt, [(0, chunk_size-len(inpt)),(0, 0)], 
                mode='constant')
            # add each inputs split to accumulators
            X = np.concatenate([X, inpt[np.newaxis, np.newaxis]], axis=0)
            y = np.concatenate([y, label[np.newaxis]], axis=0) 

    return X, y
```

When I attempt converting the above `df`, the operation takes nearly 2hrs, so I cancelled it.

```
Input, Label = transform(df, 100)
```

Is the there a way I can optimize the code to speed up? I am using Ubuntu 18.04 with 16GB RAM  running jupyter notebook.

**EDIT**

Expected output (using subset of `df`):

```
Input, Label = transform(df[:300], 100)
Input.shape
 (3, 1, 100, 4)

Input
array([[[[ 1.76300000e+01,  0.00000000e+00, -7.14402619e-04,
           2.09028008e+02],
         [ 1.76300000e+01, -9.28723404e-02,  7.08974649e-03,
           5.61162369e+01],
         [ 1.70000000e-01,  1.24000000e+00, -2.04000000e+00,
           1.08494680e+02],
         ...,
         [ 1.31000000e+00, -5.90000000e-01,  1.16000000e+00,
           3.72171697e+01],
         [ 7.20000000e-01,  5.70000000e-01, -1.28000000e+00,
           4.38722198e+01],
         [ 1.29000000e+00, -7.10000000e-01,  1.30000000e-01,
           5.55044975e+01]]],


       [[[ 5.80000000e-01, -5.80000000e-01,  7.60000000e-01,
           6.89803288e+01],
         [ 0.00000000e+00,  1.80000000e-01,  2.20000000e-01,
           1.31199034e+02],
         [ 1.80000000e-01,  4.00000000e-01, -4.80000000e-01,
           1.09246728e+02],
         ...,
         [ 5.80000000e-01,  1.70000000e-01, -1.30000000e-01,
           2.50337736e+02],
         [ 7.50000000e-01,  4.00000000e-02,  2.40000000e-01,
           1.94073476e+02],
         [ 7.90000000e-01,  2.80000000e-01, -8.10000000e-01,
           1.94731287e+02]]],


       [[[ 1.07000000e+00, -5.30000000e-01,  6.30000000e-01,
           2.02516564e+02],
         [ 5.40000000e-01,  1.00000000e-01,  2.80000000e-01,
           3.74852074e+01],
         [ 6.40000000e-01,  3.80000000e-01, -7.70000000e-01,
           2.56066654e+02],
         ...,
         [ 3.90000000e-01,  1.14000000e+00, -7.20000000e-01,
           5.72686112e+01],
         [ 1.53000000e+00,  4.20000000e-01, -4.30000000e-01,
           1.62305984e+01],
         [ 1.95000000e+00, -1.00000000e-02,  1.10000000e-01,
           2.43819280e+01]]]])
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Review, to increase odds of more detailed answers you could include the `performance` tag to your question.

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! Just so we don't have to parse the code to understand the desired output, can you include a sample of your desired output?

Comment: @Dannnno I added the expected output using subset of the dataframe (`df[:300]`) in question edit.

Comment: Did you check how much time it takes for the *groupby* operation? If that’s the bottleneck or one of the bottlenecks, you could consider using **VAEX** or **Modin** to speed it up in *pandas*. The rest of your code uses *numpy* and fills in zeroes to make the sizes of groups the same. This could potentially require a lot more memory to store the same information on disk and also on you RAM. You could consider using sparse matrices in that case to keep the memory footprint of the multidimensional array manageable.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve by converting the dataframe to this ndarray? Maybe the better solution would be to skip the transformation and work with the dataframe directly?

Comment: @mkrieger1 I want to tranform the dataset into fixed-size segments each of shape `(1,100,4)` then feed the array as input to a convolutional neural net

Comment: For NN, CNN etc. plz use tensorflow and power of GPUs or maybe Dask.

Comment: @VisheshMangla I know, but I have to preprocess the data in a way comfortable with CNN requirements first before feeding it to the network, which is what I am trying to do here.

Comment: Have you heard of tensorflow image pipelines? If not try it.

Answer (score 1):

Use [cProfile](https://docs.python.org/3/library/profile.html#module-cProfile)
to determine what portion of the function
is consuming the bulk of the elapsed time.

---

Add a [unit test](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase)
that times a somewhat large run
and verifies no regressions as the code is maintained.

---

The `.groupby('id')` is potentially expensive.
Consider first sorting values, and using `.set_index('id')`.

---

Per-row storage really matters when you have 21 M rows.
Consider using `int16` or `float32` .dtypes where feasible.

---

The public API of `transform()` hands back some very large final objects:

```
    return X, y
```

Consider offering an API with a more economical memory
footprint, where within the loop you generate small
intermediate objects:

```
        yield X, y
```

Or use [.to_hdf](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_hdf.html)
and return a filename rather than a very large object.

---

An inner loop allocates memory in this way:

```
            X = np.concatenate([X, inpt[np.newaxis, np.newaxis]], axis=0)
            y = np.concatenate([y, label[np.newaxis]], axis=0)
```

Repeatedly extending a numpy allocation can involve
lots of copying, with quadratic total cost.
Prefer to identify the total number of rows up-front,
and do the allocation all at once.
If it needs to, it's better for a loop to overwrite
pre-allocated storage than to keep requesting additional storage.